# Why my Telegram bot doesn't work in the terminal on my computer?

Tags: ruby, terminal, telegram-bot

I am an absolute beginner in telegram bots.
I found a guide online at https://www.process.st/telegram-bot/ that should teach me how to build my first bot using ruby. I have followed the guide (installing ruby and bundler) but somehow I am note able to run the bot, nothing happens and the terminal display two errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from bot.rb:1:in `<main>'
    1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- telegram-bot (LoadError)
```

The bot directory is called **telegram-bot** and has 3 files inside:

```
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
bot.rb
```

The problem occurs when I type `ruby bot.rb` in my terminal

Comment: My guess is you've misspelled `telegram_bot` in your bot.rb file. It's with an underscore, not a hyphen.

Comment: Damn, just tried using ```telegram_bot```instead of ```telegram-bot```in my bot.rb file and it works, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the misspelling of `telegram_bot`, I was using the wrong spelling `telegram-bot` in my bot.rb file, [thanks to Casper for providing me the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58560254/why-my-telegram-bot-doesnt-work-in-the-terminal-on-my-computer#comment103439781_58560254)